# how to update value in dom for a php session variable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When my page is initially loaded, my session variable has no value.  When the user logs into the system, the php variable is then set with a value, however the onclick function(which is built when the page is initially loaded) has no value for that parameter - therefore when the user clicks the button, the resulting page does not have the session variable.

I believe the problem is that when the dom is built on the load of the page, the variable has no value at that point, but how do I rebuild the dom object to contain the variable after the user logs in?  or is this just not possible?  I just need append to the onclick function to add the userid of the person that recently logged in.

Comment: you have tagged your question with ajax, that's it!

Comment: Could we see some code please?

Comment: If the user gets logged in via AJAX, your ajax call's response should have some user related data in it. Can you not access that in the success callback?

Answer (score 2):

PHP generates site before sending it to user, so when the login is not via AJAX, you may consider putting the session variable directly in the page code like this:

```
<a class="mybtn" href="#" onclick="javascript:somefunction('<?php echo $_SESSION['myvar'];?>')">CLICK ME</a>
```

or via jquery event:

```
<script>
 $('.mybtn').click(function(){
  var myvar = '<?php echo $_SESSION['myvar'];?>';
  do_something_with_myvar(myvar);
 });
</script>
```

If using ajax, simply define the variable from response:

```
$.post('login.php','login=xxx&pass=yyy',function(res){
   window.myvar = res; // lets say that login function returns that variable
});
```

and then:

```
<script>
 $('.mybtn').click(function(){
  do_something_with_myvar(myvar);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to commit a POST/GET using AJAX to trigger a php script on the back-end that would update your session as you see fit, or get the value of the session, or whatever it is you are doing in general. An example...

Simple jQuery post:

```
$.post('my_session_info.php', function(data)
{
   $('#my_element_id').val(data.sess_value);
},'json');
```

PHP side:

```
echo json_encode(array("sess_value"=>$_SESSION['my_session_var']));
```